# how to use same column twice with different criteria with one common column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
ID  P_ID  Cost
1   101   1000
2   101   1050
3   101   1100
4   102   5000
5   102   2000
6   102   6000
7   103   3000
8   103   5000
9   103   4000
```

I want to use 'Cost' column twice to fetch first and last inserted value in cost corresponding to each P_ID
I want output as:

```
P_ID  First_Cost  Last_Cost
101    1000         1100
102    5000         6000
103    3000         4000
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: probably something with group by p_id and select max(cost) as last_cost, min(cost) as first_cost (or something)

Comment: Does ID ***reliably*** indicate "first" and "last"?

Comment: Yes, ID is identity column so it does reliably indicate "first" and "last"

Comment: ...until someone uses `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;` or issues a reseed, sure...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point, 'reliably' is sometimes relative...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH t AS 
(
  SELECT P_ID, Cost, 
    f = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID),
    l = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID DESC)
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT t.P_ID, t.Cost, t2.Cost
FROM t INNER JOIN t AS t2
ON t.P_ID = t2.P_ID
WHERE t.f = 1 AND t2.l = 1;
```

In 2012 you will be able to use `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  P_ID, 
  FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID),
  FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID DESC)
FROM dbo.tablename;
```

You get a slightly more favorable plan if you remove the `DISTINCT` and instead use `ROW_NUMBER()` with the same partitioning to eliminate multiple rows with the same `P_ID`:

```
;WITH t AS
(
  SELECT
   P_ID, 
   f = FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID),
   l = FIRST_VALUE(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID DESC),
   r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY ID)
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT P_ID, f, l FROM t WHERE r = 1;
```

Why not `LAST_VALUE()`, you ask? Well, it doesn't work like you might expect. For more details, [see the comments under the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help.. This query works fine.. Is it possible to create a view using this query?

Comment: Yes, just slap CREATE VIEW at the beginning, take out the leading `;`, and name those two `Cost` columns differently.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.P_ID, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = t.minID THEN Cost ELSE 0 END) as FirstCost,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = t.maxID THEN Cost ELSE 0 END) as LastCost
FROM myTable
JOIN (
  SELECT P_ID, MIN(ID) as minID, MAX(ID) as maxID
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY P_ID) t ON myTable.ID IN (t.minID, t.maxID)
GROUP BY t.P_ID
```

Admittedly, @AaronBertrand's approach is cleaner here. However, this solution will work on older versions of SQL Server (that don't support CTE's or window functions), or on pretty much any other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want first and last in terms of Min and Max, or do you want which one was entered first and which one was entered last?  If you want Min and max you can group by.

SELECT P_ID, MIN(Cost), MAX(Cost) FROM table_name GROUP BY P_ID

Comment: Do you have an EnteredDateTime column? How do you determine what was entered first and last respectively?

Comment: @Shiva With the ID column i think?

Comment: This is incorrect.  It gets the lowest and highest cost, not the first and last cost.

Comment: My apologies, I read the question wrong at first.  I agree with Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does your thing also, just without self joins or subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   P_ID
  ,MIN(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID) as FirstCost
  ,MAX(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID) as LastCost
FROM Table
```

Comment: Same problem as @sweaty's answer - this gets lowest and highest cost, not first and last.